# Как запустить 2д объект в рандомную сторону с помощью AddForce?

Tags: unity3d

Всем привет! Пытаюсь сделать механику, при которой объект будет выпускаться при появлении в рандомную сторону. Сделал это так:

```
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    Vector2 direction = new Vector2((float)Random.Range(-30, 30), (float)Random.Range(-30, 30));

    rb.AddForce(direction * 4);
```

Но возникла проблема, direction будет равно, к примеру, 1 1, то объект будет перемещаться очень медленно, как можно сделать это лучше или исправить эту проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для направления не нужно использовать ненормализованные вектора(такие, у которых длина больше 1). Рандомишь нормализованный вектор и применяешь нужную силу в этом направлении.
Если каждый раз нужна разная сила, то рандомишь силу.

```
var direction = Random.insideUnitCircle.normalized;//рандомное нормализованное направление

_rigidbody.AddForce(direction * _force);// _force - сила, которую нужно применить к телу
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Все работает, как надо!

Answer (score 1):

Смотри, для того что бы "пнуть" объект тебе нужно приложит к нему силу имеющую направление.
Направление в нашем случае определит `Vector2`.
Для силы "пинка" потребуется переменная, допустим `float force = 30`

P.S. Если тебе нужно регулировать силу в двух осях, можно завести, либо 2 переменные:

`float forceHor = 30f` и `float forceVer = 15f`. Или обозначить тот же `Vector2 forceV = (30f, 15f)`

Итак, теперь дело за малым, сгенерировать случайное направление, например этой строчкой:

```
Vector2 dir = new Vector2(Random.Range(-1f, 1f), Random.Range(-1f, 1f));
```

Теперь у нас есть полностью случайное направление. Применим его к объекту:

```
RigidBody2d _rb //Кешируем(задаём значение) её в Start, сразу или когда потребуется.
//Если у нас 2 переменные, отвечающие за силу "пинка":
_rb.AddForce(new Vector2(dir.x * forceHor, dir.x * forceVer), forceMode.Impulse)
//Если у нас одна общая переменная:
_rb.AddForce(dir * force, forceMode.Impulse)
```

В данном коде у нас была переменная `Vector2 dir` = от -1 до 1, что по **x**, что по **y**. Конечно, объект полетит медленно, имея даже максимальные значение `x = 1, y = 1`. Но кто нам мешает этот вектор скорости домножить на силу "пинка". В итоге получится нормальный такой "пинок".

Надеюсь помог! Спасибо!

Comment: Для получения рандомного направления в юнити уже существует `Random.insideUnitCircle / insideUnitSphere`. Он возвращает нормализованный вектор. В твоем случае вектор не будет нормализован, т.к. его длина вполне может быть и 2 и 0.5 и 1. Соответственно, направление будет влиять на скорость движения, что, мягко говоря, не очень и ошибку автора вопроса не решает. Можешь заменить свое направление на то, что в моем ответе в первой строчке.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ)